# Maximization of correlation coefficient. The canonical correlation

Tags: correlation, canonical-correlation

The idea of the Canonical correlation is to maximize the correlation between two vectors $(Y,X)$ using 2 vector of weights $(\alpha,\beta)$. My problem is that I have a dependent variable $Y$ and a set of independent variables $X$ and I need to find the maximum correlation between them. The target function to maximize is: corr= $\frac{\sum_{Y,\alpha X}}{\sum_Y^{0.5} \sum_{\alpha X}^{0.5}}$

Is it possible? Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: i think you are a bit imprecise with your definitiions, and so it is hard to know what exactly do you want. CCA is not using vectors of weights but matrices of weights, and Y and X are usually also consedered to be matrices in the case of CCA. The correlation is maximized between created canonical variates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.